# Installing wordpress in sub-directory with another app's .htaccess in root directory

Tags: .htaccess

So I have a .htaccess at the root directory of example.com:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L,QSA]
```

Now I'm installing wordpress at example.com/blog/, but after uploading wordpress files there, it's 404 error when I visit http://www.example.com/blog/

My take is I should modify the .htaccess in the root directory of example.com or the request is redirected to /index.php rather than /blog/index.php

So I added this line to the .htaccess in the root directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
```

And the whole thing looked like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L,QSA]
```

But it doesn't work neither. It's still 404 error when you visit http://www.example.com/blog/ so I couldn't even install wordpress there.

How should I modify the .htaccess in the root directory to make this work? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's not a .htaccess rewrite issue but a permission issue because I have suPHP installed which demands all files to be 644 and all directories to be 755 and all scripts are owned by the user.

So this question is meanless...